# Quick(er) way to check whether a word is english by comparing it against a whitelist of english words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to eliminate all non-english words from many (100k) preprocssed text files (porter stemmed and lowercased, dropped all non a-z characters). I already parallelized the process to speed things up, but it is still painfully slow. Is there any more efficient way to do this in python?

```
englishwords = list(set(nltk.corpus.words.words()))
englishwords = [x.lower() for x in list(englishwords)]
englishwords = [ps.stem(w) for w in englishwords]
# this step takes too long:
shareholderletter= ' '.join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(shareholderletter) if w in englishwords)
```

Comment: add `englishwords=set(englishwords)` to remove dupes.

Comment: or use set comprehension instead of list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking for `somthing in otherthing` - and your `otherthing` is a list.

Lists are good for storing stuff, but lookup of "does x is in" your list takes `O(n)`.

Use a `set` instead, that drops the lookup to `O(1)` *and* it eleminate any dupes so your base -size of things to look up in drops as well if you got duplicates.

If your set does not change afterwards, go and use a `frozenset` - which is immutable.

Read: [Documentation of sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

If you use follow @DeepSpace 's suggestion, and leverage set operations you get even better performance:

```
s = set( t.lower().strip() for t in ["Some","text","in","set"])

t = set("Some text in a string that holds other words as well".lower().split())

print ( s&t )  # show me all things that are in both sets (aka intersection)
```

Output:

```
set(['text', 'some', 'in'])
```

---

See [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)

---

O(n): worstcase: your word is the last of 200k words in your list and you check the whole list - which takes 200k checks.

O(1): lookup time is constant, no matter how many items are in your datastructure, it takes the same amount of time to check if its in. To get this benefit, a `set` has a more complex storage-solution that takes slightly more memory (then a list) to perform so well on lookups.

---

Edit: worst case scenario for *not* finding a word inside a set/list:

```
import timeit

setupcode = """# list with some dupes
l = [str(i) for i in range(10000)] + [str(i) for i in range(10000)] + [str(i) for i in range(10000)]
# set of this list
s = set( l )
"""

print(timeit.timeit("""k = "10000" in l """,setup = setupcode, number=100))
print(timeit.timeit("""k = "10000" in s """,setup = setupcode, number=100))

0.03919574100000034    # checking 100 times if "10000" is in the list
0.00000512200000457    # checking 100 times if "10000" us in the set
```

Comment: While at it, make `something` a set as well and then just do set intersection. No need for a loop at all. This should speed things up in at least an order of magnitude.

Comment: This however remove duplicate words. Consider: 
`s = set( t.lower().strip() for t in ["Some","text","in","set"])`
`t = set("Some text in a string that holds other words as well and then some more text in ways".lower().split())`

`print ( s&t )  # show me all things that are in both sets (aka intersection)`

The second instance are of "text" and "in" are being ignored by the result.

Comment: @SAFEX - if you need the duplicates in your output, you can not use the `set & set` operation _**but**_ you still profit from the faster lookup in sets : `' '.join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(shareholderletter) if w in englishwords)`  if you convert `englishwords` into a set instead of a list. If you use set-operations (which would be fastest) you loose the dupes.

Comment: @SAFEX see timing difference in case a word is not in a list (using strings of numbers "0"-"9999" and looking for "10000" in a list with dupes and a set of said list

Comment: @PatrickArtner indeed, converting the whitelist into a set instead of a list significantly improves performance. Thanks again!